# VF Email Template throws List has no Rows to sObject when invoked via VF Component

Tags: visualforce-component, email-template, send-email, vf-email-template

I'm facing an issue with VF Email Template. The error is not very Clear :

> "Error     Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: List
>   has no rows for assignment to SObject. Please try editing your markup
>   to correct the problem. "

This is my controller :

(Adding the method which returns list has no rows)

```
// in this method flight Id is returning values, but the FlightService list is empty.

public List<Flight_Service__c> getFlightService()
{
        List<Flight_Service__c> FlightService = new List<Flight_Service__c>();

        for(Flight_Service__c eachFlight : [SELECT id,Vendor_Service__r.Account__c,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Name,
                                            Name , 
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Service_Type__c,
                                            Cleaning_Services__c,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Email__c,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Email_2__c,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Email_3__c,
                                            Flight__r.Airport_Origin_IATA__c,
                                            Flight__r.Airport_Origin_ICAO__c,
                                            Flight_Services__c ,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Phone,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Phone_2__c ,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Phone_3__c ,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Vendor_Primary_Contact_Phone__c,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Vendor_Primary_Contact_Email__c,
                                            Vendor_Service__r.Account__r.Primary_Contact__r.Name
                                            FROM Flight_Service__c 
                                            WHERE Flight__c IN :FlightIds
                                            Order by Flight__r.Airport_Origin_IATA__c]){
                                                if(eachFlight != null)
                                                    FlightService.add(eachFlight);    
                                            }

        System.debug('FlightService*** '+FlightService);
        return FlightService;
}
```

This is my VF Component:

```
<apex:component controller="CAMMessageController" access="global" >
    <apex:attribute name="OpptyId" type="Id" description="Opportunity Id" assignTo="{!opportunityId}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="cId" type="Id" description="Case Id" assignTo="{!caseId}"/>
    hello
</apex:component>
```

This is my VF Email Template:

I'm not sure what to provide here for Case Id. Case Id and Opportunity Id are passed in the URL of the VF Page.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Sample" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Opportunity">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<!-- hard coded contact Id for now -->
<c:CAMMessage OpptyId="{!relatedTo.Id}" cId="5002C000005Cd11QAC">
</c:CAMMessage>
Hello
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Please let me know what should be done to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chinmai,

The issue lies at this statement.

```
if(eachFlight != null)

FlightService.add(eachFlight);
```

Instead try doing it like this.

```
if(eachFlight.size()>0)

FlightService.add(eachFlight);
```

Please refer to the below article for more information about the error.
['List has no rows for assignment to SObject' error](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000159853&type=1)

Thanks